# 404 page in error log for VisitorIdentificationCSS.aspx and VIChecker.aspx in CD environment

Tags: xdb

I have sitecore 9.1 XP Scaled installed in each server with respective roles  cm,cd,processing,etc.
but in cd server log i could see following error in log

: Loading the redirect url content. Item url= /sitecore/content/Home/layouts/system/visitoridentificationcss   /layouts/system/VisitorIdentificationCSS.aspx?1620195560787

Shows 404 page in log

i verified these pages are there in layout/system folder

can you please let me know any setting/config to be updated ?

Comment: How do you render this VisitorIdentification link?  `sitecore/content/Home/layouts/system/visitoridentificationcss` definitely looks like your url has been rendered incorrectly and/or rewritten

Comment: Hi Marks, Greetings to you , in cshtml we have @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()

Comment: Where is this "Loading the redirect url content" coming from? Do you have any (custom) code in place that is causing this text in the logs?  I had such an issue once and it was related to custom code that broke that call - so you might want to check where that log is created.

Comment: @Gatogordo , we have a log for 404 pages where we see which item is  causing 404 and on log the redirection page to 404 is logged /sitecore/content/xxx/xxx/Home/layouts/system/visitoridentificationcss